# VSTS APIs: How to get the VSTS user profile from PAT?

Tags: api, azure-devops

I am working on a PowerShell script where I need to get the VSTS user profile from user PAT. I have checked the VSTS API reference but none of them seems to work.

I have also check the VSTS accounts API but it is not working. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/account/accounts/list#account ]

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use PAT (Basic Auth type) to [list accounts by REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/account/accounts/list).

The REST API to list accounts needs **[OAuth 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=vsts)**. After get the access token of OAuth 2.0, you need to use the **Bearer Token** auth type to request the REST API.

Comment: Thanks for your response, can you explain this in more detail or you know any document, or you know the procedure of getting the user profile through a PAT.

Comment: @ShubhRocksGoel You can not achieve user profile through PAT since basic auth type is not supported for the REST API to list accounts.

Comment: In this case, is it possible to get the permissions data for the provided PAT, i.e. how many permissions are available for this PAT. For ex: whether the PAT is having Manage permissions on a specific agent pool or not?

Comment: @ShubhRocksGoel There is no such REST API to get PAT authorized scopes. Besides, this is a different question from what you initially asked. So if the question you initially asked has been solved, you can accept the answer :)